# calling method in webapi controller .net core passing string in uri does not work

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to call a method in a webapiController(.net core) from my test

**If my request object has an Id as string it does not work ,as an int it does**

what Am I doing wrong in my noddy sample?

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task WhyDoesNotWorkWithIdAsString()
    {
        string thisQueryDoesNotWork = "http://localhost:1111/api/v1/shop/customers?id=1";
        string thisQueryWorksProvidedTheIdIsAnInt = "http://localhost:1111/api/v1/shop/customers/1";
        var response = await client.GetAsync(thisQueryDoesNotWork);
        var response2 = await client.GetAsync(thisQueryWorksProvidedTheIdIsAnInt);

        //omitted asserts
    }


[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ShopController: Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}",Name ="GetCustomerAsync")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(GetCustomerResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
            //more ProducesResponseType omitted
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerAsync([FromQuery]GetCustomerRequest request)
    {
        //code omitted
    }
}


public class GetCustomerRequest
{
    Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // public int Id { get; set; }   //works with int but not with a string

}
```

}

Also is below correct

[FromQuery]=use Get only
[FromBody]=use Put-Post

is there a link with explanation when to use this parameter binding?

many thanks

Comment: Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
[Route("{id}",Name ="GetCustomerAsync")]
```

`{id}` template parameter is part of the route but in the action parameter is it being requested via `[FromQuery]`, which is why it is not matching.

It is expecting

```
http://localhost:1111/api/v1/shop/customers/1
```

But your are sending

```
http://localhost:1111/api/v1/shop/customers?id=1
```

which is why the second link works and the first does not.

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

As for the concern about `[From*]` attributes

> `[FromHeader]`, `[FromQuery]`, `[FromRoute]`, `[FromForm]`: Use these to specify the exact binding source you want to apply.
>   ...
>   `[FromBody]`: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the request.

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what the problem is, Name of the httpget or route must match the one you setup in the link

Comment: @nkosi I understand that u use [frombody] for put and post but when do u use from query vs from route